# JavaScript prototypes: replace a function

Tags: javascript

I want to decorate a function of a JavaScript "class" (prototype):

```
SomeClass = function() { this.someVar = 5; };

SomeClass.prototype = {
    foo: function(arg) { /* do something with this.someVar */ }
}
```

However, I cannot change the source of `SomeClass` nor am I able to influence the instance creation of `SomeClass` instances.

Therefore I thought about doing the following:

```
var oldFoo = SomeClass.prototype.foo;
SomeClass.prototype.foo = function(arg) {
    console.log("Yey, decorating!");
    oldFoo(arg);
};
```

This seems to work fine, however, due to function scoping `oldFoo` cannot access `someVar` anymore (the `this` object is now `window`). How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate it correctly. What's happening is that since you're calling `oldFoo` like a bare function the `this` value is set to undefined (or the global object in non-strict mode).

Apply the method with the arguments and set the `this` value explicitly:

```
oldFoo.apply(this, arguments); // use the same `this` and same arguments as called.
```

Note that in order to be really correct - you also need to return the result. So in total your code should look something like:

```
SomeClass.prototype.foo = function(arg) {
    console.log("Yey, decorating!");
    return oldFoo.apply(this, arguments); // alternatively capture the return value
};                                        // and process it and then return it
```